# JavaScript AddEventListener exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment, this code is working perfectly for me:

```
function click(event){
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var text = document.createElement('textarea');
    text.multiline = true;
    text.cols = 30;
    text.rows = 6;
    text.style.cssText = "position: absolute; margin-left:" + event.clientX + "px; margin-top:" + (event.clientY - 50) + "px;";
    header.parentNode.insertBefore(text, header.nextSibling);
}
document.addEventListener("click", click);
```

But I'm wondering if you can stop it from activating when you click on the text area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Test the `target-node` using `event.target.nodeName`

```js
function click(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'TEXTAREA') {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var text = document.createElement('textarea');
    text.multiline = true;
    text.cols = 30;
    text.rows = 6;
    text.style.cssText = "position: absolute; margin-left:" + event.clientX + "px; margin-top:" + (event.clientY - 50) + "px;";
    header.parentNode.insertBefore(text, header.nextSibling);
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<header id='header'>Header</header>
```

Comment: In the unlikely event that someone is using XHTML properly, I'll note that the node name will be in lower case. In the vast majority of cases where people are using HTML, or using XHTML incorrectly, it'll be in all caps. So I'm always paranoid: `event.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'TEXTAREA'`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Updated! Is is about `IE9 and <IE9` ?

Comment: No, it's because in XHTML, the element's name is `textarea` and XHTML is case-sensitive (because it's XML). HTML is not case-sensitive and element names are normalized to all caps, but XHTML is a different beast.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it! Thanks ;)